# Isomorphism method

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

There is this exercise that goes like:
Let $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ ∈ R be such that $x_1 < x_2 < x_3 < x_4$ and consider the polynomials
$p_1(x), p_2(x), p_3(x), p_4(x) ∈ P_3\ $  defined by :

$p_1(x) = \frac{(x−x_2)(x−x_3)(x−x_4)}{(x_1 − x_2)(x_1 − x_3)(x_1 − x_4)}$

$p_2(x) = \frac{(x−x_1)(x−x_3)(x−x_4)}{(x_2 − x_1)(x_2 − x_3)(x_2 − x_4)}$

$p_3(x) = \frac{(x−x_1)(x−x_2)(x−x_4)}{(x_3 − x_1)(x_3 − x_2)(x_3 − x_4)}$

$p_4(x) =\frac{(x−x_1)(x−x_2)(x−x_3)}{(x_4 − x_1)(x_4 − x_2)(x_4 − x_3)}$

Show that $T: P_3 \to  R^4$ defined by

$$T(p) =(p(x_1) , p(x_2) , p(x_3), p(x_4) )$$

for $p \in P_3$ is an isomorphism.

How do I do that?

Comment: Maybe you could make some use of the particular polynomials $p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4$.

Comment: I dont see how :'( is the way I proposed wrong? sorry I am not familiar enough with isomorphisms

Comment: You wrote $p(x)$ when you meant $T$.  How do you know what the rank of $T$ is?

Comment: yeah maybe but I couldn't see any other way

Comment: its a vector with 4 rows so its rank is 4, no? oh well, I dont even know anymore

Comment: $T$ is not a vector or a matrix, it is a linear map.   However, a matrix with 4 rows might not have rank 4.

Comment: I edited your question.  Did I define the linear map $T$ as you wanted it?  It doesn't matter if $T(p)$ is written as a row vector or a column vector.

Comment: lso, I can't reason what $T(p)$ (or $p(x)$) means. The definition doesn't seem to connect $p_1$, $p_2$, $p_3$ and $p_4$ to $T(p)$.

Comment: I believe $\{p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4\}$ is a basis for $P^3$. Then you could write some $p\in P^3$ as a linear combination of them, and $T(p)$ would be clear.

Comment: The above idea was developed in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

We'll prove that $\{p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4\}$ is a linearly independent set of $P^3$. Notice first that $p_i(x_j) = \delta_{ij}$. Let

$$
\alpha_1p_1(x)+\alpha_1p_2(x)+\alpha_3p_3(x)+\alpha_4p_4(x) = 0
$$

At $x = x_1$, only $p_1\neq 0$, so $\alpha_1$ = 0. We do that for $x_2$, $x_3$ and $x_4$ to complete the proof. Since $\dim P^3 = 4$, this is a basis, implying that we can write some arbitrary $p\in P^3$ as

$$
p(x) = c_1p_1(x)+c_1p_2(x)+c_3p_3(x)+c_4p_4(x)
$$

Again, notice that $p(x_i) = c_i p_i(x_i) = c_i$ for each $i$. This makes the $T$ linear and well defined. It is easy to see that its kernel is zero dimensional, because

\begin{align}
T(p) = 0 
\iff&(p(x_1),p(x_2),p(x_3),p(x_4) = 0                     \\
\iff& p(x_i)  =c_i                    = 0 \text{ for each } i
\end{align}

And since $\dim\mathbb{R}^4 = \dim P^3 = 4$, the rank-nullity theorem says that $\dim(\text{im}(T))= 4$. This completes the proof.